# Helping with for in loop

Tags: swift

```
for i in 1...6 {

    for j in 1...7-i {
        print(" ", terminator: "")
    }

    for j in 1...2*i-1 {
        print("*", terminator: "")
    }
    print("")
}
```

guys, I dont understand what does the line2 meaning?
and also line 5

someone can explain it to me please thanks a lot

Comment: Print "i", "j" in each line, it may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a nice triangle. :)

The **first** `for loop` represents the number of times the inner loops will execute.
That is: 6 times (1...6).

The **second** `for loop` represents the spaces at the beginning of each line.
It will execute 7 times minus the current iteration number of the outer loop, represent by `i`.
For example, during the *first iteration*:

`i` = 1
`j` will be 1...(7 - 6); that is 6 times (1...6).
Six **white spaces** will be put on the first line.

*Second iteration*:
`i` = 2
`j` will be 1...(7 - 2); that is 5 times (1...5).
Five white spaces will be put on the second line.

Not for the **third and final** `for loop`: it adds `*` characters to the output according to the outer loop (`i`).
For example, during the *first iteration*:
`i` = 1
`j` will be 1...(2 * 1) - 1; that is one time (1...1).
One `*` character will be put on the first line.

*Third iteration*:
`i` = 3
`j` will be 1...(2 * 3) - 1; that is five times (1...5).
Five `*` characters will be put on the third line.

Interesting pieces of code like that deserve to be put in a Playground:

[image: playground]

We can see exactly what's going on. o/

More info on `for-in loops` with `numeric ranges`: [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID121)

Comment: Thanks Bro. That was excellent answer. I just found the exercise in swift programming book, just confuse how does the second loop works. Now clear. Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is small explanation for you:

```
for i in 1...6 { // 1) This is loop from 1 to 6 it is the depth of the triangle.

    for j in 1...7-i { // 2) This is empty space " " loop for filling left side of the triangle.
        print(" ", terminator: "")
    }

    for j in 1...2*i-1 { // 3) This is * loop for filling of the triangle parts.
        print("*", terminator: "")
    }
    print("")
}
```

1. We do iteration from 1 to 6 times in each loop j will be changed from 1 till 6.
2. This iteration is filling left part with empty space but with infomration that we should always left empty space with formula (7 - loop 1 position (from 1 till 6))
3. This iteration fills * of out triangle with condtion (2 * loop 1 position (from 1 till 6) - 1)