# Python: printing user defined string a successive number of times

Tags: python, string, function, for-loop

I am EXTREMELY new to programming. I am trying to write a function that prints the string '$' a number of times defined by the user, successively reaching that number in the same amount of lines. For instance, if the number is 5, then the output should be

$

$$

$$$

$$$$

$$$$$

I have already tried a for loop. I honestly don't even know what sort of function would accomplish the desired result. I know this isn't right, but am I at least on the right track?

```py
def func():
    number = int(input('Enter a positive integer:  '))
    for i in range(number):
        print('$'*number)
        number = number + int(input('Enter a positive integer:  '))
    print()
func()
```

All I can  get it to do is print the string the specified number of times, in the same loop. And if the user inputs another integer, then it will print one line with the old value and the new added together.

Comment: Nice discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802772/helping-with-for-in-loop/43803261#43803261

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47779201/swift-4-need-help-to-make-triangle-using/53427298#53427298

Comment: @matt those questions are both based on the swift programming language. I am pretty sure the OP is asking about python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `number` for the print statement, instead use `i` which is the counter or the index.

This should solve your problem:

```py
def func():
    number = int(input('Enter a positive integer: ')) 
    for i in range(1, number+1): 
        print('$'*i) # you need to use 'i' here and not 'number' so that the number of $ signs increases every time

func()
```

Comment: If the answer helped you out, you should click on the green checkmark beside it to signify that it solved your problem. Your welcome :)